# Приложение под Android вылетает при запуске, okhttp

Tags: java, android, http, okhttp

При попытке отправить http запрос приложение вылетает, использовал библиотеку okhttp

```
package com.example.work.okhttp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    //создаем запрос к серверу
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("https://reqres.in/api/users/2")
            .build();


    //выполняем запрос и получаем ответ
    Response response = null;
    try {
        response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        String result = response.body().string();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
}
```

вот мои логи

```
05-24 13:05:16.582 14314-14314/com.example.work.okhttp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.work.okhttp, PID: 14314
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.work.okhttp/com.example.work.okhttp.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2925)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3060)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:110)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1800)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6649)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826)
 Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1509)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:117)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:105)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1154)
    at okhttp3.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:172)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:138)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:80)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:178)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:129)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:98)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:124)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:170)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:60)
    at com.example.work.okhttp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7130)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7121)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1262)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2905)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3060) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:110) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1800) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6649) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

У вас `NetworkOnMainThreadException` - нельзя запросы в сеть из основного потока делать, начиная с [API=11](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html). Ваш код как раз из основного и пытается в сеть идти.

Вам надо или делать запрос в другом потоке силами либы (метод `enqueue`) либо текущий код запустить в другом потоке. Либо средствами Java, создав новый `Thread`, либо средствами андроид (AsyncTask, Loader), либо сторонними библиотеками (RxJava)

По вариантам:

1. Метод `Call#enqueue()` - самый простой способ. Официальный пример [тут](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/AsynchronousGet.java).
2. `Thread` - слишком низкоуровнево.
3. `AsyncTask` - устарел и не очень удобен
4. `Loader` - замена для `AsyncTask`. Излишне сложен, неудобен.
5. `RxJava` - стильно, модно, молодёжно. Из минусов - надо освоить базовые принципы реактивного программирования. Зато потом его можно везде и всюду и на всех языках во всех средах использовать.

Comment: Поправочка: начиная с версии API 11 (Android 3.0 a.k.a Honeycomb)

Comment: @A.Shakhov, да действительно) Обновил ответ)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб RxJava это зло!я уже забыл что есть и . треды ))))только на реакте все и пишу ((

Comment: @elik, это треды зло) Спасибо Rx-у, что мы про них забыли)))

Comment: @ЮрийСПб мужик благодаря тебе я научился программировать )))

Comment: @ЮрийСПб щас в Москве в очень солидной компании.Будешь тут дай обезательно знать я тебя угощу чем нибудь и расскажу свою историю )

Comment: @elik, круто, поздравляю) Рад, что смог помочь) Договорились - буду в Москве - дам знать)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб , не могли бы вы показать как мне это сделать, просто я в java и в android программировании вообще не силен и сам пытаюсь что-то писать. Можете хотя бы скинуть хорошие статьи, которые показывают работу RXJava, или любые другие статьи где показывают как правильно составлять http запросы

Comment: @АрыстанКалиакпаров, если rxJava сложно, то используйте средства либы. Вот их официальный пример для запроса не в основном потоке: https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/AsynchronousGet.java